# Understanding xfuncname by git diff

Tags: regex, git, git-diff, re2

I would like to know how exactly `git diff` applies the expression provided to xfuncname to the result and if it is possible to delegate the search for the hunk header text to another program.

Context: I would like to change the xfuncname setting for my `git diff` to display a usable output for a xml file. An example xml that would look like this:

```
<layer1-1>
</layer1-1>
<layer1-2>
    <layer2-1>
    </layer2-1>
    <layer2-2>
    </layer2-2>
    <layer2-3>
        <layer3-1>
            [...]
            changes
            [...]
        </layer3-1>
        <layer3-2>
        </layer3-2>
        <layer3-2>
        </layer3-2>
    </layer2-3>
</layer1-2>
<layer1-3>
</layer1-3>
```

And ideally, the output with the modified hunk header would look like this

```
@@ -15 +15 @@ <layer1-2><layer2-3><layer3-1>
[...]
-notchanged
+changed
[...]
```

My observations imply that `git diff` applies the regular expression to the part of the file *before* the difference, takes the *last* match and from that the *first capture group*; and it uses the `m` flag. Is that a suitable description?

As RE2 apparently supports neither [backreferences](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/101) nor [lookaheads](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/156), I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do can be achieved by this method. Is there a way to specify a custom program/script that receives the diff as input so I can specify a hunk header myself?

Comment: While the idea seems interesting, parsing an XPath with a regex is quite hard to achieve, furthermore if lookaround are not supported. I'm affraid you can't do that with `xfuncname`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the internal diff generator.  See the `diff.external` section of https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config.